# Text on terminal is cleared

Tags: python

```
import time
from cursor import hide_input_cursor, show_input_cursor

def animation(timem):
    hide_input_cursor()
    for i in range(1, timem + 1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("." * i, end="\r")
    show_input_cursor()
animation(8)
```

Hello, does anyone understand why the dots are cleared from terminal after the code has ended?

I tried everything, but nothing helped

Answer (score 0):

The dots are cleared for the same reason the script does what it does: it prints some periods, then a carriage return (`\r`) to place the cursor at the beginning of the line, then overwrite the line by the next sequence of periods.

After the last sequence, the cursor is placed at the beginning of the line again, and then the line is overwritten by your shell's prompt.

If you want the periods to remain shown, print a *newline* (`\n`) after the last sequence:

```
for i in range(1, timem + 1):
  time.sleep(1)
  print("." * i, end="\r")
print("") # print an implicit newline
show_input_cursor()
```